# Return value from function in "function pointer mode"

Tags: c++, c, stm32

First, sorry for my English. I'm brazilian still trying to learn (english,and programming).

I'm trying to create a firmware application (STM32 uc), that access other firmware (my address was divided in BL + FWA + FWB), but I have one problem and can't find the reason.
FWB needs to access a function on FWA, to use less flash area.
I can access the function itself, execute any operations inside it, but when return is reached, it gives-me an HardFault.
I'm using scatter file to use memory shared on both FWA and B.

```
  LR_IROM1 0x08004000 0x00004000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08004000 0x00004000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 UNINIT 0x00001000  {  ; No init data
   *(.noinit)
  }
  RW_IRAM2 0x20001000 0x00004000  {
   .ANY (+RW +ZI) //RW data
  }
}
```

and my funcition is defined as

```
uint getInt(void) __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x8006000")));//My fw was at 0x4000, total size is 0x4000,
                                                                  //so space is not the problem.
uint getInt(void){
    return 42;
}
```

On my application (running on FWA for testing itself, but no result), I'm trying to call it this way:

```
uint (*fun_ptr)(void) = (uint(*)(void))0x8006000;
uint _get_int= fun_ptr();
uint result = _get_int();
```

Edit:
When using

```
IntFunc p =             getInt;
uint ccccc = p();
uint aaaa = getInt();
```

all options work correcty, the problem is when using address.

As I mentioned, I can enter the function "getInt()", I can execute any code instruction inside it, but when "return 42" is reached, I have a HardFault.

I find another way to do this, using structs, working, but I think that is very important to understand this problem, understand where is the error, this helps to don't make mistakes again.

EDIT 2:
I want to understand the problem, not just simply get an solution.
This method works to me:
main.h file

```
typedef struct bootloaderApi bootloaderApi;
typedef   unsigned int (*do_something_t)(void);
struct bootloaderApi{
    do_something_t do_something;
};
```

and Main.c:

```
const struct bootloaderApi api __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x8005000")))
= {.do_something = &getInt}; //address 0x5000 to test.
```

and using it as

```
struct bootloaderApi *apit = (struct bootloaderApi *)0x8005000;
uint pa = api.do_something();
```

it works correctly, pa returns me the uint 42.

Thanks.

Comment: *but when "return 42" is reached, I have a HardFault.* -- I have not worked on stm32, but in my experience from Windows, whenever a `return` crashes, that usually indicates a calling convention mismatch between the caller and callee.  Note that your function is very simple, so to me that is what I would suspect or something similar.

Comment: If you're not familiar with what calling conventions are, [here is a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).  Of course if you know what they are, then you know what I'm speaking of.

Comment: Also, is the environment when the function is being prepared knows that a `uint` (in terms of size) is being returned and not something that is of a different byte size?  If not, then this could be another reason (I see that you say it works for struct, but not for a very simple `uint`).  Also, I would stick to using known C++ types, like `uint32_t` or similar instead of `uint`, just to make it explicit as to what the actual type is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Thanks for your link, i'll read it.
Sorry, I think that I explain wrong:  "when I use one struct with the function inside it, mapped the function getInt to the members of struct, and mapped the struct to address, without mapping getInt function itself, it works. When I call mystruct.getIntMethod(), it works correctly. I will edit the question to put the working method, to clarify it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I edited my question, to explain what works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
uint (*fun_ptr)(void) = (uint(*)(void))0x8006001;
```

because all function pointers on this architecture must be odd.

The address is the real address of the first instruction (which is always even) plus one.  The last bit indicates that the instruction uses the "thumb" instruction set, not the "arm" instruction set which is not available on this device.

Comment: Thanks. I can't try it now, but this makes sense to me. When I try, I'll come back to tell you.

Comment: I can't wait, and tested it now. IT WORKS.
Thank you very much, not for the code itself, but for the explaining the reason about that.

Comment: Tom, one more question: the setting of address is correct? Setting at 0x8006000 and accessing at 0x8006001, or the setting needs to be at 0x8006001 too?
Do you have any link where I can study a little more?

Comment: The address of the instruction is 8006000.  Thumb instructions are 16 or 32 bits, so the byte at 8006001 is also part of the instruction, but to get the instruction aligned correctly you must put 8006000 in the linker script.  When the processor is told to call a function at 8006001 it subtracts one and fetches from the address 8006000.  It performs a 32-bit load which includes both bytes, but the address in the program counter register excludes the lowest bit.